# How to check the history of advanced settings for web sites in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have configured the physical path (SAN Storage) in advanced settings in the IIS

Looks like the path has been changed recently and the files are not getting saved

Is there a way where I can check what the previous value was for the particular field??

I need to know what was the previous value for `Physical Path`

PFB the image

[image]

Comment: I believe there is no built-in solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a history for that in IIS.

If you don't have much directory in wwwroot and you know how the website looks, you can try setting the physical path to the directory within inetpub > wwwroot starting with the root.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, someone might have enabled the logging for IIS configuration. Check if thats the case and you can see the changes.

check following article for reference
[IIS config auditing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/19/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-iis-configuration-auditing.aspx)